# Sometime footer show and show time not show wkhtmltopdf

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I m trying to add page number in footer this is my code

```
var pdfInfo = {};
var x = document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
for (var i in x)
{
    var z = x[i].split('=',2);
    pdfInfo[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);
}
function getPdfInfo() {
    var page = pdfInfo.page || 1;
    var pageCount = pdfInfo.topage || 1;
    document.getElementById('page').innerText = page;
    document.getElementById('topage').innerText = pageCount;
}
```

i m calling this js function on body load

```
<body onload="getPdfInfo()">
<div style="text-align:right; font-family: tahoma !important; font-size: 12px !important;">
     Page
     <span id="page" class="page"></span>
     of
     <span id="topage" class="topage"></span>
 </div>
</body>
```

but some time footer show and some time not show and some time footer show on first page and not show on second page

Comment: What framework you using codeigniter or laravel?

Comment: i m using Codeignitor

Answer (score 0):

You wrap your `getPdfInfo` code in a method that is called on page load, but not the code above it. Is there a reason it all can't be wrapped in that method? Then you can be sure that your `pdfInfo` object is populated all the time.

One thing you can do to debug this issue is to ensure that your `pdfInfo` object is properly set at the time the document is loaded by inserting a `console.log(pdfInfo)` statement at the very top of your method.

Comment: You should use a browser that supports it, such as the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, or Safari.

To confirm, your `console.log` statement needs to be the first line you call in your `getPdfInfo` function definition.

Comment: i am using latest version of firefox and chrome console working in case of html page but when in open pdf browser console not show any result

Comment: A PDF browser cannot run Javascript in it. However, you can wrap your PDF in a Javascript-based viewer, such as [ViewerJS](http://viewerjs.org/), and use Javascript _outside_ of it to interact with it.